# Create or increment a field in Mongoid with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have a model like this:

```
class Invoice
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :local, type: String
  field :date, type: DateTime
  field :total, type: Float
end

class LogInvoice
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :date, type: Date
  field :local, type: String
  field :summary, type: Hash
end
```

The field summary is a Hash like this:

```
summary = {invoices : 0, amount : 0.0}
```

For each invoice stored, I must create an LogInvoice for that day with total number of Invoice (count of Invoice) in LogInvoice.summary[:invoices] and with the total ammount of money (summatory of Invoice.total) in LogInvoice.summary[:amount]

If the Invoice exist I must to update the LogInvoice of that day.

I can't know if a object existe because LogInvoice.find() returns an exception if it doesn't, so how can I update an existing object LogInvoice or created if it doesn't?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question you should do something like this:

```
my_invoice_criteria = Invoice.all # or Invoice.where date: the_date_I_want or anything else
my_invoice_criteria.each do |invoice|
 log_invoice = LogInvoice.find_or_create_by date: invoice.obtain_proper_date
 #Use this for atomic persistence
 log_invoice.inc :"summary.invoices" => 1
 log_invoice.inc :"summary.amount" => invoice.total
 #Use this for standard persistence
 log_invoice.summary[:invoices]+=1
 log_invoice.summary[:amount]+=invoice.total
 log_invoice.save
end
```

Ref:
[Atomic persistence](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html#atomic) Docs
[Standard persistence](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html#standard) Docs

Comment: It doesn't work. The first way (atomic persistence) throws `undefined method 'total'` and the second one throws `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`. Do I have to create a Hash first? But will it autoincrement too? Note: thanks for the find_or_create_by solution

Comment: Ready! I added two little changes. First, I added to my model `field :summary, type: Hash, :default => {}` and second one, I had to autoincrement in the ugly way, like this: `a = a.to_i + 1` because I received an **(undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass)**. Thanks anyway

Comment: your default hash could be 
    :default=> {:invoices=>0, :amount=>0} 
so you will avoid further "undefined methor __ for nil:NilClass"